# How to add a logo to my readthedocs - logo rendering at 0px wide

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

This happens locally via sphinx running readthedocs theme, it also happens in readthedocs.io.

I have added an svg logo (actually it's just the downloaded rtd logo.svg copied from their site for testing).

I've added the settings to **conf.py** and html builds fine.

```
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
html_logo = 'logo.svg'
html_theme_options = {
    'logo_only': True,
    'display_version': False,
}
```

If I inspect the logo class in Firefox it is set to "auto", if I add a width in px, the logo appears.

I feel as if I am missing something about the configuration of the readthedocs theme in the conf.py file?

Surely I should not have to hack at the CSS manually: I see no indication of altered CSS in the Readthedocs.io site when looking at their source.

I'm looking for an elegant solution - I do not want updates to readthedocs theme to break my site because I have been overriding the theme's CSS.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#other-configuration) your configuration appears correct and should work. It's also consistent with the theme's documentation's [`conf.py`](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/a3ab477aaa23f3b7ab7d62c7abc2cc74102ab2b8/docs/conf.py#L44-L49). Perhaps compare your HTML and CSS against another example, specifically the sphinx_rtd_theme's docs?

Comment: Thanks, I have done that but I cannot yet see the issue. The computed value on RTD for the logo is width: 262.1px; height: 60px; but the css shows "auto" for both. I cannot see where these figures are coming from. Adding a css file import to the conf.py as per instructions on RTD with the following (below) in the custom.css solves the problem. Note that !important is not required. I do have not found the cause of the problem and don't have css skills to diagnose.

.wy-side-nav-search > a img.logo, .wy-side-nav-search .wy-dropdown > a img.logo {
width: 262.1px;
height: 60px;
}

Comment: Suggest using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your output. We cannot diagnose what we cannot see.

Comment: I have the same issue with svg, but it just works when I convert the image to png. Does not make me happy though :/

Comment: Have you checked the builders? Some builders do not support .svg images
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html

Comment: Same problem. sphinx-rtd-theme v0.5.0, sphinx v3.4.3

Answer (score 15):

You're doing correctly

```
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
html_logo = "mepro_headshot.png"
html_theme_options = {
    'logo_only': True,
    'display_version': False,
}
```

I just added the logo in my `docs/source/` and when you run `make html`, it copies your `png`or `svg` files into `docs/html/_static/`. As mentioned in the documentation: [***New in version 0.4.1: The image file will be copied to the _static directory of the output HTML, but only if the file does not already exist there.***](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_logo)

```
├── docs
│   │   └── html
│   │       ├── _static
│   │       │   ├── mepro_headshot.png
│   │       │   ├── mepro_headshot.svg
│   └── source
│       ├── _images
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── mepro_headshot.png
│       ├── mepro_headshot.svg
```

and it seems both

`svg`

[image]
and

`png` works

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, I've resolved it by adding the _static directory at the html_logo parameter.

```
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
html_logo = "_static/logo_rw.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with .svg width auto zero px. For anyone that does want to set the css here is a solution:

`sphinx-rtd-theme v0.5.0, sphinx v3.4.3`

`docs/_build/html/_static/css/custom.css`:

```css
/* 
`width:auto` was rendering 0px wide for .svg files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215996/how-to-add-a-logo-to-my-readthedocs-logo-rendering-at-0px-wide
*/
.wy-side-nav-search .wy-dropdown > a img.logo, .wy-side-nav-search > a img.logo {
    width: 275px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I put this css in a file named custom.css in my _static directory and then set html_static_path = ['_static'] and html_css_files = ['custom.css'] in my conf.py and it was sorted. Many thanks!