# Configure logo for ReadTheDocs site using MkDocs engine

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

Maybe a missing feature; not sure.

How would we go about adding the site/project logo top left in a ReadTheDocs site using the MkDocs engine?

At https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html#adding-a-logo (and some [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59215996/131929)) it appears configuring logo is unrelated to RTD or MkDocs but is actually targeting the [Sphinx RTD theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme).

Comment: Answered here: https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/2537